# java.exe can't seem to find a .java file in the current working directory

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error

I installed Java on Windows 10. It installed here: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1`.  I made sure the path had been modified to include the `bin` folder and `java.exe`. I can type 'java' in a cmd window and get the java usage message. So, that works.

Then I installed Eclipse. I went through the tutorial section walkthru to create the `HelloWorld` program. And it runs in Eclipse. Here it is:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

---

Now that I have that set up correctly, I wanted to try running it without Eclipse. So, I copied the `HelloWorld.java` source file from the Eclipse work space to a folder I created under Documents, `C:\Users\kris4\Documents\java`.

I open a cmd window, cd to `C:\Users\kris4\Documents\java`, and do a `dir`:

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is A656-1FA0

 Directory of C:\Users\kris4\Documents\java

05/24/2018  03:22 PM    <DIR>          .
05/24/2018  03:22 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/24/2018  11:20 AM               160 HelloWorld.java
               1 File(s)            160 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  116,141,473,792 bytes free
```

There it is...

But, when I execute, `java HelloWorld.java` I get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld.java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld.java
```

The file is right there in the working directory, and the file is a copy of a working Eclipse workspace file. WTH!  Looking on the internet, I thought java needs `CLASSPATH` to find the source, so I defined a variable `CLASSPATH` to be the directory `HelloWorld.java` resides in. Still no luck.

Obviously, being new to this, I'm missing something very basic in the cmdline environment that should be there, but I honestly expected `java.exe` to look in the current working directory for a file given as an argument, like any other program.

Can one of you folks help me out?

Comment: "But, when I execute, java HelloWorld.java..." -- You can't run a source file.  First you need to compile HelloWorld.java into HelloWorld.class using javac.

Comment: If you look in the bin folder of your eclipse project, you could likely use (or copy) the "HelloWorld.class" file there... `java -cp %BIN_FOLDER% HelloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

not just

```
java HelloWorld.java
```